# jQuery check in array and return true or false

Tags: jquery, arrays, logic

I have an array of pages

```
var $pages = ["events", "template", "privacy", "terms", "mentor", "party", "getinvolved", "tools"];
```

What I want to do is

```
  if ( $body[0].id !== anyOfThePageInTheArray ) {
    //do something here
    });
```

How can I do like if the page that they are on is not one of the page that is in the array.

I have tried `.inArray` and `.each` but I think maybe I'm doing it wrong or something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The native `Array.indexOf` works fine:

```
if ($pages.indexOf($body[0].id) === -1) {
    // It's not in there
}
```

But if you insist on jQuery:

```
if ($.inArray($body[0].id, $pages) === -1) {
    // It's not in there
}
```

Comment: @karthikr: OP's question had `$body[0].id !== anyOfThePageInTheArray`, so it looks like the condition is checking if the element isn't in the array.

Comment: it doesn't work for me I don't know why :/ 

It is like it never check the whole array and already returned.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
if($pages.indexOf($body[0].id) == -1){
    //code here
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use

```
if($.inArray($body[0].id,$pages) === -1)
```

When the second argument isn't in the array (first argument), it will return -1. Otherwise, it returns the index of the element.

By the way, `$body[0].id` returns e.g. "events", or is a number?

Comment: I think it is returning the page name for that argument

Comment: Before the if you could debug with `console.log($body[0].id); console.log($pages); ` to know what's going wrong...

Comment: matiaslaporte  I think I know what is wrong, I forgot my closing bracket on something, so this code works, but FYI your equal should be `===`